# Access object property while working with another object in ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my project I got a JSON response via GET request. The subTopics will be selected by the user and stored. Afterwards I send a POST request to the server with the selected ids.

Example JSON1: (from GET request)

```
{  
"TopicList" :
  [{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "topic1",
    "number": "1",
    "subTopics": [
       {
          "id": "4567",
          "name": "subTopic1.1",
          "number": "1.1"
       },
       {
          "id": "9876",
          "name": "subTopic1.2",
          "number": :1.2"
       }
    ]
  }]
}
```

In the POST response I get another JSON object from the server, which I have to show in my HTML view as a table. In the response JSON I have the subTopics id (selected by the user) but I do not have the subTopic name associated with the id.

I have to show the subTopic name in my table which is available in a separate object(see above JSON file). I don't know how to access the first JSON object while working with another.

My table view looks like this,

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="tableRow in searchCtrl.tableViewData" ng-click="tableRow.expanded = !tableRow.expanded">
    <td>{{tableRow.project.name}}</td>
    <td>{{tableRow.project.number}}</td>
    <td>{{tableRow.project.endDate | date}}</td>
    <td>{{tableRow.topicIds[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{tableRow.matching.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the 4th row: `<td>{{tableRow.topicIds[0]}}</td>` shows the id. How can I show the topicName?

Any help would be appreciable.

**EDIT**

In my controller this variable contains the above JSON object.

```
if (!self.topic) {
        searchService.getTopic().then(
             function (response) {
                self.topic = response.data;
             },
             function (error) {
                alert("Server is not found");
             }
       );
 }
```

So, the topic variable contains the response JSON object. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @csbarnes : thanks for making question more understandable...+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that takes an id and returns the subTopic.

```
$scope.getSubTopic = function(id) {
  var selectedSubTopic = {};

  angular.forEach(subTopics, function(subTopic) {
    // loop through subTopics until a matching id is found
    if (subTopic.id === id) {
      selectedSubTopic = subTopic;
      return;
    }
  });

  return selectedSubTopic;
};
```

then you can update your fourth row to:

```
<td>{{getSubTopic(tableRow.topicIds[0]).name}}</td>
```

This assumes you have an array named subTopics.

**Edit**

As mentioned in my comment this will end up performing pretty slow for heavy pages and/or large datasets. You will likely want to generate a map object for the subTopics for quick access. The downside being you have to generate this each time the TopicList is modified.

```
function generateSubTopicMap(topics) {
  var map = {};

  angular.forEach(topics, function(topic) {
    angular.forEach(topic.subTopics, function(subTopic) {
      // use this if you want the map to reference the same data
      // (i.e. updating subTopic.name will update the map at the same time)
      map[subTopic.id] = subTopic;

      // use this if you don't want the map to reference the same data
      // map[subTopic.id] = {};
      // angular.copy(subTopic, map[subTopic.id]);

      // you can also add the parent id here if you need access to it
      // this will modify the original object if you use the first method!
      // map[subTopic.id].parentId = topic.id
    });
  });

  return map;
}
```

The output looks like:

```
{
  "4567": {
    "id": "4567",
    "name": "subTopic1.1",
    "number": "1.1"
  },
  "9876": {
    "id": "9876",
    "name": "subTopic1.2",
    "number": :1.2"
  }
}
```

With this you would call it after every GET request and pass it the array of topics.

```
// where topics is the response from the GET request
$scope.subTopics = generateSubTopicMap(topics);
```

And finally to display you just need:

```
<td>{{subTopics[tableRow.topicIds[0])].name}}</td>
```

**Edit 2**

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrgoatsj/) showing how to use the second method. All you have to do is pass the array containing your TopicList to `generateSubTopicMap` and it returns an object with the keys as subTopic ids and the value as the subTopic itself.

I wouldn't worry about my first solution. It isn't going to be performant inside an ng-repeat or grabbing 2nd level objects.

Comment: thank for your answer. You mentioned this subTopics array. This is what I got in my response JSON object, a list of topicIds, right?

Comment: That will get the topic name and not the subTopic name. You could iterate over each topic and add all subTopics to a single array, at which point the above code will work for you. You could also modify getSubTopic to iterate over each topic, then each topic's subTopics to find the right one but this end up performing pretty slow. Both of these solutions are less than ideal and won't scale very well. I would recommend generating a map of the subtopics with the key being their id. That way you don't need to have an extra loop while binding and you have quick access to all subTopics.

Comment: I have tried both the solutions from you. But It won't work for me. But I am still confuse about this subTopics array. In my controller there is a array called topics, which holds the above JSON object. When I tried to put topics in the place of subTopics then it shows me error that topics is not defined. The question is still there that how to access third level object property into forEach iteration?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a jsfiddle showing how to use the function in the second solution. Don't worry about the first answer, if you still have to generate the subTopics array it is better to generate a map object instead.

Comment: Hey, I tried the fiddle solution also but somehow it is not working for me. I tried the same dummy data also to check weather this function is working or not. In my console, it doesn't show me error and the topicId column remains empty. ???

Comment: As I have updated in EDIT. please check that out. Maybe it could help you.

Comment: You are going to put `$scope.subTopics = generateSubTopicMap(self.topic);` below the `self.topic = response.data;` line. The subTopic id shouldn't be displayed, it should be the subTopic name, correct? If you just click the jsfiddle, the first row should be: `project 1 1.0 Aug 20, 2015 subTopic2.1 5`

Comment: If you still need help I suggest creating a jsfiddle with as much relevant code as possible and putting it in your original question. Right now you should be able to take in the TopicList (JSON1 in your question) and get all the subTopics in a single object ($scope.subTopics). From there you can access any subTopic with just an id, `.topicIds[0]`, in your question.

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem. Thank you for your answer...:)